# I'm struggling about a not working ManyToMany relationship in Symfony 2 with doctrine as ORM

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, many-to-many

Hi there and thanks ahead to anybody who will try to help.

I'm pretty new to Symfony and doctrine and I cannot figure out, why my ticket entity is stored without the ManyToMany Realtionship. 
I tried very hard, did anything I found for some days but finally I need help.

Here we are

Ticket

```
<pre>
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
    use AppBundle\Entity\Computer; 

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="tickets")
     */
    class Ticket {

        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        protected $creator;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        protected $owner;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="tickets")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $category;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Type", inversedBy="tickets")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        protected $type;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string")
         */
        protected $subject;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Computer", inversedBy="tickets", cascade={"persist"})
         * @ORM\JoinTable(name="inventory_computer_join",
         *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
         *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="computer_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
         *)
         */
        protected $computer;
    [...]
     /**
         * Add computer
         *
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Computer $computer
         *
         * @return Ticket
         */
        public function addComputer(\AppBundle\Entity\Computer $computer)
        {
            $this->computers[] = $computer;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Remove computer
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Computer $computer
         */
        public function removeComputer(\AppBundle\Entity\Computer $computer)
        {
            $this->computers->removeElement($computer);
        }

        /**
         * Get computers
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         */
        public function getComputers()
        {
            return $this->computers;
        }
    }
</pre>
```

Computer

```
<pre>
    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
    use AppBundle\Entity\Ticket;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="inventory_computer")
     */
    class Computer
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Ticket", mappedBy="computer")
         */
        protected $tickets;
        [...]
      /**
         * Add ticket
         *
         * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Ticket $ticket
         *
         * @return Computer
         */
        public function addTicket(\AppBundle\Entity\Ticket $ticket)
        {
            $this->tickets[] = $ticket;

            return $this;
        }
</pre>
```

Controller

```
<pre>
    /**
         * @Route("admint/createTicket", name="AdminTicketErstellen")
         */
        public function AdminCreateTicketAction(Request $request) {

            $ticket = new Ticket;
            $form = $this->createForm(TicketType::class, $ticket, array(
                'method' => 'GET'
            ));

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($ticket);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirectToRoute('measure_servers');
            }

            return $this->render( 'sysadmin/pages/AdminCreateTicket.html.twig', array(
                    'ticket' => $form->createView(),
                )
            );
        }
</pre>
```

Comment: Have you got in database your table **inventory_computer_join** after the command `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` ? Before persisting your ticket if you dump the variable **$ticket** do you have computers linked to it ? Where is exactly your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want storage ManyToMany try it;

First:

Change `protected $commputer;` to `protected $computers` at Ticket.php entity.
Because, you using $this->computers at addComputer() or removeComputer() .

Second: `* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Ticket", mappedBy="computer")` to `mappedBy="computers"` at Computer.php entity.

You can storage ticket with computer, try it at Controller:
    $ticket = new Ticket();
    $computer = new Computer();

```
$ticket->setCreator(4);
$ticket->setOwner(3);
$computer->addTicket($ticket);
$ticket->addComputer($computer);

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($computer);
$em->persist($ticket);
$em->flush();
```